# An elementary identical equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given positive integer $n$. Let *perfect numbers* be integers which can be written as $a_1^n+\cdots+a_n^n$, where $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that the product of $n$ perfect numbers is still perfect number.

I think the proof is to directly construct $a_i$ of the product, but I can't remember the detail.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you give us an idea of what you have already done or attempted? A bit more context for the problem could also help us help you--I'm wondering if there's anything else this connects to.

Comment: For example, in the case where $n=2$, $(x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)={(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)}^2+{(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)}^2$，thus the product of two perfect numbers is still perfect. I'm trying to extend it to $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You "guess" this identical equation holds true for all $n\in \Bbb N$, or this identical equation indeed holds true but you don't know how to prove it?

Comment: I guess there exists indentical equations for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, but i can't find them.

Comment: @OrthoPole So, this identical equation may be false?

Comment: A positive integer is called *perfect* if it equals its sum of proper divisors. It is not good to use a different definition now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your clarification (Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity), which gives me a way to answer. This is readily disproven for $n=3$ thanks to the sum of three cubes problem:

For $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$, we know that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \not \equiv 4$ or $5 \pmod 9$. However, if we have $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x \equiv 1 \pmod 9, y \equiv 2 \pmod 9,$ and $z \equiv 2 \pmod 9$, then $x,y,$ and $z$ can all be expressed as the sum of three cubes, but their product, $xyz \equiv 4 \pmod 9$, cannot. QED.

Similarly, all integer $x^4 \equiv 0,1 \pmod{16}$, so all sums of four fourth powers will be in $\{0,1,2,3,4\} \pmod{16}$. But $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \equiv 12 \pmod{16}$, which cannot be a sum of four fourth powers. I suspect one can find similar analogous arguments for other powers.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think your proof is correct. For the case $n = 3$, you just proved that "the three numbers $x,y,z$ **cannot be** $(1,2,2)$ in modulo $9$ if $xyz$ is perfect number". But there may exist "$(x,y,z)$ that **are not** $(1,2,2)$ in modulo $9$ and still satisfy $xyz$ is perfect number"

Comment: The OP's statement is specifically: "Prove that the product of n perfect numbers is still [a] perfect number." $10, 11, 20$ are all sums of three cubes. $2200$ is not.

Comment: That said, doing some brute forcing turns up the fact that finding the modulus that works for the proof when $n$ is prime is difficult. The correct (smallest) modulus displays interesting patterns for non-primes; if $n$ is a power of $2$, the modulus of the following power of two, and the same for powers of three. For $n=6$, either $8$ or $9$ works. For $n=10$, the modulus is $25$. It appears that if $n$ is even, then the modulus used for $2n$ is twice the modulus used for $n$.

Comment: Ok I see now, especially with the counter-example $(10,11,20)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proof.